# Add SD to dotplot in R

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to make my graphs in R and now I have a problem that I can't solve. I use the `dotplot` function to plot the mean of 16 treatments. This works out pretty well, on the y axis are my variables (treatment names) and on the x axis is the value. But I really want to add the standard deviation to my points and I tried different things I found via internet but it doesn't work. If somebody could help me (in an easy way), I would be so happy!

Thank you so much for reading this!

I have:

```
library(lattice)
d2 <- colMeans(d, na.rm=TRUE)
var.labels <- f  ###  f includes the names of my treatments
SD <- sd(d, na.rm=TRUE)
new.data <- data.frame(var.labels=factor(var.labels, levels=f), d2, SD)
dotplot(var.labels~d2, data=new.data)
```

Comment: Is that function `dotplot` in package lattice? If yes, please add `library(lattice)` to your code and add the lattice tag to your question.

Comment: Yes, it is in lattice. Ähm,...I am sorry but do you mean with lattice tag this: ‘lattice’ version 0.20-10 ? Sorry for not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution might be:

```
dotplot(var.labels~d2+SD, data=new.data)
```

a nice comparison about different dot-charts (standard R, lattice and ggplot2) can be found here: [Summarising data using dot plots](http://www.r-bloggers.com/summarising-data-using-dot-plots/)

hth

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I tried your suggestion but it just added one additional point next to my data points. I assume this is the variation to the upper side. So there must be any way to tell R that I need the SD to both sides and if possible as a line. If you would have an idea for this it would be so great! Cause I am creating a poster in the moment and this is the last graph that doesn´t want to work. I also tried to use the dotchart function:      m=c(mean(d,na.rm=TRUE))
dotchart2(m, labels=f, xlim=c(0,9))    Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Ahh, ok. I think you want to indicate the SD at each data point. Try this `dotplot(var.labels~d2, data=new.data, panel=panel.lines(SD, SD*(-1)))`

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. It is still not the right thing cause the lines are vertical and have to be horizontal because on the x axis is my value and the lines have all the same length what can´t be correct. But this is the first time that a line goes through my data points, so I feel it is very close to the correct command. Do you have another idea? I am so thankful for your help!

Comment: Try this one `d3 <- d2+SD`, 
`d4 <- d2-SD`,
`new.data <- data.frame(var.labels=factor(var.labels), d2, SD, d3, d4)`,
`dotplot(var.labels~d2+d3+d4, data=new.data,
          panel=llines(d3, d4))`